# API - get menu items from specific menu

Tags: joomla-4.x, restful-api

I can't guess how to get menu items from a specific menu via API.

I use:

https://github.com/alexandreelise/j4x-api-collection

https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/9617873/Szzj9yJy#6ac385da-724b-4b5b-b020-21c4d9fc9411

I get for example specific menu

```
{{base_url}}/{{base_path}}/menus/{{app}}/{{menu_id}}
```

But how to view menu items for this menu?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to do this at the moment. You can only list all menu items per application:

```
{{base_url}}/{{base_path}}/menus/{{app}}/items
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Sharky said, basically you need to add in Postman what is called a Api Test which is nothing more than javascript and the Chai JS library.

[image]

You see the tests tab

You need to add this code in the test tab to filter out just the menu items of a given menutype. On my example site I have mainmenu and then I created using the API another site menu with menutype "menu", then added a menu item to it again via the Api.

Now I had:

mainmenu:

- menutitem1
- menuitem2

and

menu:

- menuitem3

With the following js code you can fetch only what you want using the tests tab of a request.

```
pm.test("My custom site menu only items", () => {
   const allMenuItems = pm.response.json();
   
   const menuTypeToFilterBy = 'menu';

   let onlySpecificMenuItems = allMenuItems['data'].filter((item) => {
       return item['attributes']['menutype'] === menuTypeToFilterBy;
   });

   console.log(onlySpecificMenuItems);
   
   //TODO: Do whatever you want with this filtered result

});
```